# Django не применяет локальный шрифт

Tags: html, css, python, django

Django не применяет локальный шрифт к селектору, однако все остальное пашет. Шрифт, подключаемый по линку с google-fonts, применяется как положено. Чем это можно пофиксить?

СSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-face-name: This;
  src: url("../assets/font/This-Regular.woff");
}
.header-logo {
  font-family: This, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Указать не относительный url, а абсолютный.

Comment: В браузер дев туле на ваш элемент смотрели? Может что-то перебивает стиль? Что именно вы подразумеваете под "не применяет"?

Comment: @Klimenkomud стили не перебиваются. Если применить этот шрифт (локальный) просто к к-л селектору на статичной страничке (без всего), то он срабатывает. В приложении джанги применяется только внешний шрифт

Comment: Но он то хоть что-то должен выдать по поводу этого шрифта: может у вас ошибка в консоли появилась(типа `404 Not Found`). Или джанга тупо игнорирует написанные вами строчки и "не видит" их? Но скорее всего вопрос в непонятном для меня `font-face-name`, попробуйте вместо этого использовать `font-family`

Comment: `font-face-name` на данный момент `deprecated`, вот и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно подключили шрифты:
`font-face-name` на данный момент - `deprecated` согласно [Документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/font-face-name).
А правильно будет так:

```
@font-face {
font-family: This;
  src: url("../assets/font/This-Regular.woff");
}
.header-logo {
  font-family: This, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, ошибка была в этом. Все заработало!

Comment: @etterwin Пожалуйста :)